# opening a local pdf file through firefox webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, cucumber-java

I want to open a pdf document through firefox webdriver.I used the command

> driver.get("file:///root/file.pdf");

but the document does not open.How should I do that?

Comment: did you provide the correct path, Open that file using any browser and copy that value and pass that in `driver.get("correct path")`

Comment: @SudhaVelan: yes the path provided is correct.I have provided file://<<file.absolutepath>>.But in the report the screen shown is blank,and i am not able to capture any DOM id.

Comment: and the thing is that any other .html file opens,but pdf file gives a blank page.

Comment: It will take sometime to load.

Comment: That does not work.With the same path file:///root/file.html opens up but file:///root/file.pdf does not.

Comment: Its not throwing any error?

Comment: No,on findElement_by_id throwing no_such_element_exception,which is obvious as the file has not loaded.

Comment: You are using linux machine? if so, check the file access mode.

Comment: I gave full permission to the pdf file but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue,by setting

> firefoxProfile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", false );